# Set publisher name in JWS application using given certificate

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start, signing, jar-signing

I have obtained a certificate by a *trusted authority* (have been given a .pfx file).

I signed all my .jar files with jarsigner like this:

```
jarsigner -storetype pkcs12 -keystore my_pfx_file.pfx -storepass my_store_pwd -signedjar Smy_jar.jar my_jar.jar
```

Then I exported the certificate from the keystore to create a .cer file.

What else do I have to do so that I don't get the message from "Unknown Publisher" and instead has the Company name?

Comment: Applets can be terribly prone to cache, and JWS can cache launch files and digital certificates.  Before you try anything else, create an entirely new applet (& launch file for it), sign the applet using the certificate & test it in the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. It was a problem with the .pfx file. I could see the certificate chain in the mmc console, but when I used:
`keytool -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore my_pfx_file.pfx`,
 
 I saw the certificate chain length was 1.
So I exported the certificate from the mmc console. Only this time, I check the box that says "Include all certificates in the certification path if possible". I got a new .pfx file with which I signed my jars and it works perfectly.
 
This post helped me a lot to figure out what was going on: 
[How to sign java applet with .pfx file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642837/how-to-sign-java-applet-with-pfx-file)