# Get rid of the "UNKNOWN" publisher from applet security warning

Tags: java, ssl, applet, certificate, signing

I'm trying to **sign an applet** so that the **publisher** does not appear as "**UNKNOWN**" :

[image: Applet security warning showing an "UNKNOWN" publisher]

I work for an organisation and we have **our own certification authority**, **certificate chain** is the following : *ORG Root CA > ORG Trusted Certification Authority > Yann39 (me :D)*

I requested a certificate and they provided me a link to get it into the browser.
Then I exported it (from Firefox) to get the PKCS#12 file that I named **mystore.p12**.

Then I did the following to **sign my applet** :

```
/* TO KNOW THE ALIAS */
c:\testrep>keytool -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore mystore.p12
Enter keystore password:  ********

Keystore type: pkcs12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 1 entry

id de yann39, Oct 24, 2012, keyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): D7:E3:83:1D:C1:40:68:72:5F:A8:6F:AC:3A:EA:DD:47

/* CREATE FAKE CLASS FILE AND BUILD A JAR */
c:\testrep>echo test > test.class
c:\testrep>C:\oracle\dev10gr2\jdk\bin\jar cf0 test_applet.jar test.class

/* SIGN THE JAR */
c:\testrep>C:\oracle\dev10gr2\jdk\bin\jarsigner -verbose -storetype pkcs12 -keystore mystore.p12 test_applet.jar "id de yann39"
Enter Passphrase for keystore: ********
 updating: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   adding: META-INF/ID_DE_YA.SF
   adding: META-INF/ID_DE_YA.RSA
  signing: test.class

/* VERIFY THE SIGNATURE */
c:\testrep>C:\oracle\dev10gr2\jdk\bin\jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs test_applet.jar

         132 Wed Oct 24 17:49:52 CEST 2012 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
         185 Wed Oct 24 17:49:52 CEST 2012 META-INF/ID_DE_YA.SF
        4801 Wed Oct 24 17:49:52 CEST 2012 META-INF/ID_DE_YA.RSA
           0 Wed Oct 24 17:48:36 CEST 2012 META-INF/
sm         0 Wed Oct 24 17:47:46 CEST 2012 test.class

      X.509, CN=Yann39, CN=794324, CN=myname, OU=Users, OU=Organic Units,
DC=myorg, DC=ch
      X.509, CN=ORG Trusted Certification Authority, DC=myorg, DC=ch
      X.509, CN=ORG Root CA, DC=myorg, DC=ch


  s = signature was verified
  m = entry is listed in manifest
  k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
  i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope

jar verified.

c:\testrep>
```

Then I **load the appled** in my application using the following :

```
<object id="mytestapplet" width="0" height="0" style="position:absolute" type="application/x-java-applet">
<param name="archive" value="https://myhost.ch/rep/test_applet.jar">
<param name="code" value="test">
<param name="scriptable" value="true">
<param name="mayscript" value="no">
</object>
```

I read some posts like this one : [How to sign java applet with .pfx file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642837/how-to-sign-java-applet-with-pfx-file) and it seems **I should get** `smi` when verifying signed file from the jar, not only `sm` that means the certificate was not found in the keystore.

So **I thought the certificate chain was not complete**, but when running the following command, **I saw that it was not the case** :

```
c:\testrep>keytool -list -v -storetype pkcs12 -keystore mystore.p12
Enter keystore password:  ********

Keystore type: pkcs12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: id  de yann39
Creation date: Oct 24, 2012
Entry type: keyEntry
Certificate chain length: 3
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Yann39, CN=794324, CN=myname, OU=Users, OU=Organic Units,
    DC=myorg, DC=ch
Issuer: CN=ORG Trusted Certification Authority, DC=myorg, DC=ch
Serial number: 12d21eb200200000a02b
Valid from: Mon Jun 25 14:16:00 CEST 2011 until: Wed Jun 24 14:16:00 CEST 2013
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  D7:E3:83:1D:C1:41:78:72:5F:A8:6D:BD:3A:ED:DD:48
         SHA1: 24:31:1D:25:02:98:0D:F8:28:6A:F1:0E:E8:BB:04:7E:51:E2:E9:66
Certificate[2]:
Owner: CN=ORG Trusted Certification Authority, DC=myorg, DC=ch
Issuer: CN=ORG Root CA, DC=myorg, DC=ch
Serial number: 601fab4c000000000003
Valid from: Tue Oct 02 11:36:53 CEST 2006 until: Mon Oct 02 11:47:53 CEST 2016
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  51:A1:EA:33:21:2C:71:60:A1:6F:F1:22:92:A8:51:8D
         SHA1: 66:CD:70:13:27:68:F3:C2:08:F3:BE:5F:BF:D4:17:BD:85:9D:10:65
Certificate[3]:
Owner: CN=ORG Root CA, DC=myorg, DC=ch
Issuer: CN=ORG Root CA, DC=myorg, DC=ch
Serial number: 7dc0d089138d1d804b2e68e21b947412
Valid from: Tue Oct 02 10:55:19 CEST 2006 until: Sat Oct 02 11:01:47 CEST 2026
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  A2:CE:DC:7D:F5:60:D7:2C:5E:B5:29:74:9D:51:F9:49
         SHA1: DA:D8:7F:63:95:90:A2:E4:D4:1D:B9:48:FD:F4:C3:5C:FC:2B:B6:A3


*******************************************
*******************************************



c:\testrep>
```

The chain seems good.

But I **still** get the **security warning** with an **"UNKNOWN" Publisher**. **Why** ?

---

### EDIT 25-OCT-2012

I forgot to say that **it works using Internet Explorer** ("Signature has been verified" and Publisher is "Yann39"), not using Chrome or Firefox.

I tried using a **self-signed** certificate :

```
keytool -genkey -alias myalias -storetype PKCS12 -keystore mykeystore.p12 -dname "cn=Yann39, ou=UN, o=ORG, st=Geneva, c=CH"
keytool -list -v -storetype pkcs12 -keystore mykeystore.p12
echo test > test.class
C:\oracle\dev10gr2\jdk\bin\jar cf0 myapplet.jar test.class
C:\oracle\dev10gr2\jdk\bin\jarsigner -verbose -storetype pkcs12 -keystore mykeystore.p12 myapplet.jar "myalias"
C:\oracle\dev10gr2\jdk\bin\jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs myapplet.jar
```

It does not work neither in IE nor in Firefox or Chrome, normal.

I tried to add the 2 trusted certificates from my organisation but **it failed** :

```
keytool -import -alias "myalias_root" -file ORGRooTCA.crt -storetype pkcs12 -keystore mykeystore.p12
keytool -import -alias "myalias_auth" -file ORGTrustedCertificationAuthority.crt -storetype pkcs12 -keystore mykeystore.p12
```

with the error :

```
keytool error: java.security.KeyStoreException: TrustedCertEntry not supported
```

I still don't understand why it says that the certificate was not found in the keystore (`sm`) when verifying the signature.

---

### EDIT 02-NOV-2012

I finally got a reply from my Certification Authority. As code signing certificates are provided for test only (not officially supported in our organisation), they don't provide any help and they closed my ticket...

The 2 certificates **ORG Root CA** and **ORG Trusted Certification Authority** are trusted in the 3 browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome). When running my applet I still get the expected result in IE :

- **Name**: applettest
- **Publisher**: Yann39
- **From**: https://myhost.ch

But not in Firefox and Chrome :

- **Name**: test
- **Publisher**: UNKNOWN
- **From**: https://myhost.ch

Another strange thing is that as you see IE is referencing as “Name” the id of the `<object>` tag used in the HTML (*applettest*), while Firefox and Chrome are referencing the name of the main class (*test*).

What I think is that it is the same thing about the **Publisher**, IE is looking at the `CN` RDN (*Yann39*) while Firefox and Chrome are looking at the `O` RDN and cannot find one as it is not defined in my certificate.

If anyone has more information about how browsers check the certificates please share.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a guess, but it's possible that the applet dialog uses the `O=` RDN of the certificate to display who the publisher is (that's what browsers do). If you control that CA, you could try to add `O=Something` to your Subject DN to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the CA, they simply provided me the PKCS12 file. As it works only using Internet Explorer maybe other browsers are looking for `O=` while IE doesn't care about it (as usual...) ? I added some information to my post.

Comment: `jar verified.`  Oops!  Missed that.

Comment: How is it going? Have you succeeded to verify the publisher?

Comment: I have contacted my CA to get any help and to know if there could be any problem with the certificate they issued to me (as Bruno suggested, it seems strange that it does not contains the `O=` RDN.). I'm still waiting for a reply, I will update my post as soon as I get more information.

Comment: I want to ask you what is the alias as "id de yann39"?

Comment: "id de yann39" is the alias identifying the keystore entry.

Comment: @Yann39 is it the original private key?

Comment: @Yann39 see my answer additional edit

Comment: I don't made any changes to the certificate, so yes I guess it is the original private key ? About your edit: yes I exported it as described in your link, but I used "backup all", not "backup" only, else I don't get the whole certificate chain in my `.p12` file. About signing the `.jar` file, I don't skipped anything, jarsigner only ask me for the keystore password. I think keystore password and private key password are the same, it is why it is not asking for it ? I have updated my first post.

Comment: @Yann39 see my answer additional updates

Comment: As I said, I have not generated anything manually in the keystore, I simply get my cert in Firefox from a link provided by my CA. Then the only thing I can do is to export it from the browser. Using Firefox I get a `.p12` file, using IE I get a `.pfx` file, it is the same, both are containing the private key, else jarsigner would complain about it. And both are containing the full certificate chain (length:3). Of course I also tried to sign the `.jar` with the `.pfx` file but I get the same result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have your own CA and sign applets with certificates issued by that CA, then you obviously need to add that CA's certificate to the list of trusted certificate authorities.

When running inside IE, the Java plugin seems to be able to use the system list of CA, so you just need to add your CA certificate to the system certificate storage (be sure to manually choose the certificate destination as a trusted CA during the import).

When running inside Chrome or Firefox, the Java plugin for some reason does not use system certificate storage, but only its own separate certificate storage. You will get the "insecure" security warning with "UNKNOWN" publisher when running applet in these browsers if the CA's certificate is not present in the Java plugin certificate storage, regardless of whether it is in the "trusted CA" system certificate storage.

To add a certificate to Java plugin storage:

- open Java control panel
- select "Security" tab
- click "manage Certificates..." button
- select "Signer CA" option in the "Certificate type" combo-box.
- import your CA's certificate

The next time you use Chrome or Firefox to run your applet, you will have a normal "secure" security warning with the option to trust that applet forever.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't work anymore in this organization so I cannot do additional tests about this specific problem. If I remember well, of course adding the certificate to the Java keystore was working. But the goal was to avoid users having to perform this action. The conclusion seems to be that it is simply not possible. Good for security, bad for users. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add CA certificates (up to the root CA) to your p12 file before signing.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. I Added the root CA that I downloaded from the provider and added it to the p12 file (from KeyChain on the Mac). It fixed it immediately.

Answer (score 2):

The same strange "UNKNOWN" Message appeared when I changed my signing certificate. I imported the certificate of my signing keystore into cacerts (so that my self signed jar would be accepted), but the java cache held the old jarfile. Then when starting the "old" applet with the "new" certificate, a message similar to the one above appeared.

Solution: clear the java cache (via java control panel or javaws -uninstall).

This just in case someone (like myself) stumbles upon this Thread while searching for this Error Message.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to add the 2 trusted certificates from my organisation but it
>   failed :

Emm... all seems quite unclear because you demo the signing process since certs import only...

> I tried using a self-signed certificate  It does not work neither in
>   IE nor in Firefox or Chrome, normal. I tried to add the 2 trusted
>   certificates from my organisation but it failed :

Of course, it failed. Because you cannot import certs to get chain for non-original keys. And coming back to your test case...

All I can see in your test case things like:

- A) You gen maybe **myalias**  or maybe **myalias_root** and
  **myalias_auth** key(s) - give more details here
- B) You try to import **ORGRooTCA** and
  **ORGTrustedCertificationAuthority**
- C) You try to sign a test jar

In step B You try to import 2 certs. So I must ask

- Were the two certs generated by using **myalias_root** and
  **myalias_auth** CSR(s)?

If they weren't so I suppose you just skipped some steps as follows:

- A) Gen **myalias_root** and
  **myalias_auth** key(s)
- B) Gen CSR of **myalias_root**_root and **myalias_auth**
- C) Gen certs **ORGRooTCA** and **ORGTrustedCertificationAuthority** by using **myalias_root** and
  **myalias_auth** CSR(s)
- D) import the certs as **ORGRooTCA** and **ORGTrustedCertificationAuthority** to get chain
- E) Try to sign a test jar

And once again...

> I tried to add the 2 trusted certificates from my organisation but it
>   failed :

As a result, I can advice you

- A) Get not only certs from your organization but also its
  keystore **keys** the certs were generated of
- B) Or gen your own keys and your own certs by following the
  previously mentioned ABCDE steps :)

---

> I requested a certificate and they provided me a link to get it into
>   the browser. Then I exported it (from Firefox) to get the PKCS#12 file
>   that I named mystore.p12.

You manually imported it and then you exported it as described [here](http://www.pentaware.com/pw/How_to_export_a_PFX_file_from_your_firefox_browser.htm) ?

OK... it is quite interesting. If you still sure all things in your pfx right :S still I re-play the your jarsigner using demo. So you sign the test_applet.jar as

```
/* SIGN THE JAR */
c:\testrep>C:\oracle\dev10gr2\jdk\bin\jarsigner -verbose -storetype pkcs12 -keystore mystore.p12 test_applet.jar "id de yann39"
Enter Passphrase for keystore: ********
 updating: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   adding: META-INF/ID_DE_YA.SF
   adding: META-INF/ID_DE_YA.RSA
  signing: test.class
```

... it's pretty standard signing way but I want to point a little detail... I cannot see where jarsigner **demands** you to enter the "id de yann39" private key **password** :S ? All I can see you enter keystore password only ... Is the step skipped in your copy-paste version or jarsigner is really doesn't demand you to enter key password?

As a trial, I do recommend you to try sign your jar using **-keypass** arg as (see example)

```
jarsigner -keystore C:\working\mystore -storepass myspass
      -keypass dukekeypasswd MyJarFile.jar duke
```

For more details see [how to use jarsigner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/jarsigner.html) docs...

---

> I don't made any changes to the certificate, so yes I guess it is the
>   original private key ? About your edit: yes I exported it as described
>   in your link, but I used "backup all", not "backup" only, else I don't
>   get the whole certificate chain in my .p12 file. About signing the
>   .jar file, I don't skipped anything, jarsigner only ask me for the
>   keystore password. I think keystore password and private key password
>   are the same,

If you generated keys in your keystore with keytool you must know that keystore has its password and newly generated private key(s) should have its own password; So I suppose maybe something is missing here :S It would be interesting you A) import your pfx to IE and export it with IE as described [here](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4782/exporting-an-installed-code-signing-certificate-from-internet-explorer) : since the "Yes export the private key" instructions + "Include all certificates in the certification path if possible"

P.S.
Please comment if that was helpful

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but here you only speak about my last test using a self-signed certificate. It was just a test to see if it was possible to import 2 trusted certificates in the same keystore as my self-signed one, but as you said we cannot import certificates to get chain for non-original keys. It is not really the problem, I have to use the certificate provided by my CA. However thank you for the information!

Comment: No, you can't import certs for alien keys to get chain because the keys are not the original ones which the CSR was generated of; Do you have keys (alias) in your keystore which the certs were generated of?

Comment: The ONLY thing I get from my CA is the .p12 file, a keystore containing the 3 certificates (ORGRooTCA, ORGTrustedCertificationAuthority and my user certificate).