# getting UNKNOWN publisher warning message for java applets

Tags: swing, jnlp, jarsigner, jar-signing, signed-applet

recently I have upgraded to jre 1..7.45b18 and started getting the security popup saying 
Do you want to run this application
Publisher: UNKNOWN
Running applications by UNKNOWN publishers will be blocked in a future release because it is potentially unsafe and a security risk.

My jar files are self-signed using 'signjar' ant utility, can someone advice how to stop this popup from appearing. I understand something needs to be changed the way jars are signed and the java web start to recognize it.

Answer (score 2):

this is due to the security restrictions coming from Oracle.
See [Oracle Security Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/securityDialogs.html):

> If the application is self-signed or signed by an unknown authority, the publisher is shown as UNKNOWN.

This article answers this question as well:
[Get rid of the "UNKNOWN" publisher from applet security warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053922/get-rid-of-the-unknown-publisher-from-applet-security-warning)

Answer (score -1):

The below link is dead. Long live the new link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/securityDialogs.html

Comment: Why not suggest an edit to the original answer and replace the link? This post by itself doesn't provide an answer to the question. Remember that improving posts by editing is a great way to earn reputation too.