# How to set application name field for the security warning message java7u45

Tags: java, security, web-applications, parameters, applet

I developed a java applet called by Javascript functions for a web application. I would like to avoid having the application field set to **UNKNOWN**  when the security warning message (a.k.a the one asking me to allow the following application from the current website) pops up.

So far I tried to add a **name** field and an **alt** field when declaring my applet attributes in my HTML.
I also tried to add an **Application-Name** in the MANIFEST of the java applet but I keep having a warning message with application:UNKNOWN

How can I set correctly this field?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this SO [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053922/get-rid-of-the-unknown-publisher-from-applet-security-warning)?

Comment: Is the applet signed?  Does its jar have all the required [manifest attributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/manifest.html) set?

Comment: Yes the applet is signed and I paid to have a certificate associated with the public key. My problem is not with the publisher field set to unknown but the application name set to unknown.